# How to measure wave length of songs?

Tags: measure

I want to measure wave lengths of songs as I mentioned in the question. I want to find a number and according to this number I will try to decide what kind of music it is.

I found Acoustic fingerprint but I am not sure if it is going to help me.

Does anyone has ideas?

Comment: Your question makes little sense, and the tags you have used only vaguely relate to what you're asking.  When you say "measure wave lengths of songs", I assume you mean use FFT to get the majority of the frequencies (and therefore wavelengths) used in each audio file - however you could _never_ deduce the musical genre from this data.

Answer (score 0):

If a song had just one wavelength it wouldn't really be a song. (just a monotone noise)

I suggest you read up on [signal analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_analysis). There are lots of thing that define the character of a song.

EDIT: If you want an adverage of the wavelengths in a song I suggest you do a forier transform in matlab. ([here](http://matlabgeeks.com/tips-tutorials/how-to-do-a-fourier-transform-in-matlab/) is a guide)

Comment: ı will try to get average of these wavelengths and decide what kind of music it is. You can see these waves from winamp or media player. I need to convert them to int

Comment: i couldn't open it any of browsers and dont know why